# How to View the HTML Text inside a cell to a new html tab in google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets

I got this crazy idea that I know only a few could think about. My Data inside a single cell was an html text, but I can't view it in a html format, I want to know if its possible to make a link of it that opens a new tab and shows the html format of the text.

for example this one was inside the cell, but it its only viewed as text;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>NICE! YOU JUST GOT AN ORDER (#10022)</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Sample Data</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Its like, I want to view it as an HTML File, its fine if I need to open it to a new tab as long as it its viewed as html file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, the solution to escape / replace the characters can be used `<textarea>` to display the code. Just use the readonly property and remove the element's borders:

Código **CSS**

```
textarea {
  border: none;
  resize: none
}
```

Código **html**

```
<textarea readonly rows='10' cols='40'>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1- 
strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>NICE! YOU JUST GOT AN ORDER (#10022)</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p> Sample Data</p>
  </body>
</html>

</textarea>
```

Comment: is there any option to view it in HTML format? not a text only?

Comment: @Ryan IT you can replace `<` by `&lt;`  and `>`by `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Everything would be like this:

```
&lt;!doctype html&gt;
<br>
&lt;html lang="en"&gt;
<br>
&lt;head&gt;
<br>
    &lt;meta charset="UTF-8"&gt;
    <br>
    &lt;meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"&gt;
    <br>
    &lt;meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"&gt;
    <br>
    &lt;title&gt;Document&lt;/title&gt;
<br>
&lt;/head&gt;
<br>
&lt;body&gt;
<br>
&lt;/body&gt;
<br>
&lt;/html&gt;
```

I made some line breaks so that the HTML render in the best way.

Comment: Is there any way to make it simple? I want to know if its possible to make the html text viewable as as an html file format, when you just, click the cell, like a hyperlink that opens it in a new tab

Comment: @Ryan IT If there are other ways. Try to study [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML).